# Why different result outputs between the generic type and wildcard type

Tags: java, generics, polymorphism, wildcard

I know what is the difference between the generic type and the wildcard type,
but in this situation I cannot use the same way again to understand.

For short, To compare both Interfaces below

```
public interface RequestParser {
    <T extends Entity> Message<T> parseRequest(String json);
}
```

```
public interface RequestParser {
    Message<? extends Entity> parseRequest(String json);
}
```

Only the first one can compile the below codes: **(User extends Entity)**

```
Message<User> message = requestParser.parseRequest(json);
```

The one uses wildcard `?` cannot succeed.

So what exactly is the difference between them in this situation ...?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is PECS (Producer Extends Consumer Super)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2723397/what-is-pecs-producer-extends-consumer-super)

Comment: In this case you want to use the produced value and therefore it's also a consumer (linked in the duplicate)

Comment: Oops, PECS the term I never heard before, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because `Message<User>` is not a subclass of `Message<? extends Entity>`.

The issue will be more evident when trying to implement `RequestParser`.

This will fail without a cast, as `T` is not necessarily `AnotherUser`:

```
public class AnotherUser extends Entity {}

public class RequestParserImpl implements RequestParser {
    <T extends Entity> Message<T> parseRequest(String json) {
         return new Message<AnotherUser>();
    }
}
```

Whereas this will compile:

```
public class RequestParserImpl implements RequestParser {
    Message<? extends Entity> parseRequest(String json) {
         return new Message<AnotherUser>();
    }
}
```